# Brown sugar instead of white sugar

Tags: substitutions, sugar, brown-sugar

I want to replace a white (granulated) sugar in a recipe with brown sugar.  Is this a one to one substitution?

The original recipe calls for 2 cups white sugar.  Can I replace with 2 cups brown sugar?  Packed or unpacked?

Comment: What are you making?

Comment: Making a carrot cake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can...*by volume*. You'll definitely need to pack the brown sugar. The taste will be different (obviously) and the weight will be slightly different as well, but it'll work. Mind you, brown sugar **does not dissolve the way white sugar does**, so you may get some crunching if you don't combine it with your wet ingredients first.

Don't substitute by weight. Brown sugar weighs more.

Answer (score 5):

Its also worth noting that brown sugar is actually [molasses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molasses) and regular suger. Molasses has some diffrent properties like beeing higher in simple sugers meaning that it'll taste sweeter than regular sugar.

if you do substitute them one-to-one expect the cake to taste sweeter than it normaly would have.