# Can I use brown sugar in No Bake Cookies instead of Granulated Sugar?

Tags: substitutions, sugar

Can I use Brown Sugar instead of Granulated Sugar in my No Bake Cookie Recipe?

Comment: A recipe would help.

Comment: Also, what is the reason for the substitution?  Are you out of granulated sugar?  Are you looking for a different flavor profile?  It would help formulate the answer if we had some background.

Answer (score 3):

In many recipes, brown sugar and granulated sugar can be substituted for each other fairly freely. Keep in mind that brown sugar will add both color and flavor, and it has more moisture. If your recipe has a narrow moisture tolerance, you'll want to decrease the moisture elsewhere. Also, brown sugar tends to be more hygroscopic than granulated, so the product will remain softer over time.

Answer (score 1):

Today "Brown Sugar" is a mixture of [granulated sugar and molasses](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/alton-brown/homemade-dark-brown-sugar-recipe/index.html). As a substitute for 
granulated sugar brown sugar is "OK" but it will be significantly more sweet than just sugar, unless you dial back the quantity of sugar, which may be problematic for the overall recipe. Some experimentation may be required for your recipe(s) but it will get you close.

Comment: do you have a source for the sweetness of brown vs white sugar? They should be almost exactly the same, with brown being ever so slightly less (as molasses is less sweet).

Comment: I have actually encountered people saying both that brown is sweeter than white and vise-versa...
http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/14878/6279
http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Which_is_sweeter_brown_or_white_sugar#slide1

Then of course I could always reference "The Rolling Stones", but I'm not sure Mr. Jaggers opinion of "Brown Sugar" would count for much here.